# C++ Safe To Work With Char Array If First Value Of Array Is Set To Null Terminator?

Tags: c++, char, initialization, undefined-behavior, allocation

If I were to allocate a string like this would it be safe to work with? i.e. should I expect any UB when writing/reading to/from it?

```
void example()
{
    char exmapleString[32];
    char exmapleString[0] = '\0';
}
```

Even if `exmapleString` contains garbage data for not being initialized properly (i.e. `char exmapleString[32] = { 0 };`) I've set the first value of the `exmapleString` array to `\0` therefore if I were to pass it through functions like `strcpy`, `strcat`, etc... The null terminator would be pushed to the end of the string so this means this string is safe to work with if I initialize it like this and set the first value of the array to `\0`?

So far from all of the testing I've done this seems to work just fine.

This function works

```
void example()
{
    char exmapleString[32];
    char exmapleString[0] = '\0';
    strcat(exmapleString, "test");
    print(exmapleString);
}
```

But this function will (most of the time) print garbage data

```
void example()
{
    char exmapleString[32];
    strcat(exmapleString, "test");
    print(exmapleString);
}
```

Which leads me to beleive that yes indeed setting up a string like this

```
char exmapleString[32];
char exmapleString[0] = '\0';
```

Should not result in any UB. Is that correct? Or would this be considered un-safe?

Comment: Technically correct, but why not use `std::string`?

Comment: `strcat` expects **pointer to the null-terminated byte string to append to** so if you don't null terminate it, all bets are off

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code snippet?

Comment: Not sure what your use-case is, but initializing your char array to a default value could be useful: `std::fill_n(exmapleString, 32, 0);`